# Expo local notification not working in android when time format 12 hour

Tags: react-native, expo

This is My Code :
hear trigger is 24-hour format but my android is 12-hour format it is not working Please give the solution -- is there any option to enter trigger with 12-hour format? Please help me

````
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({

            content: {
                title: "My First Notification",
                body: "This is local notification Sending"
            },
            trigger: {
                hour: 13,
                minute: 13,

                repeats: true
            }
        });```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
In my case I Maintained an AsyncStorage to handle this issue. From Asyncstorage I retrieved stored data and used in trigger and i was able to receive notifications.
```

```js
In
function

const storeData = async() => {
  var items = {
    //if your stored data is an object u can retrieve them in following way
    storedDateValue: mydate,
    storedExerciseValue: exerciseDuration,
  };
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("Notifications_Key", JSON.stringify(items));
  } catch (e) {}
};

const readData = async() => {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Notifications_Key");
  try {
    if (value !== null) {
      let storedValues = JSON.parse(value);
      console.log(value)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  readData();
}, []);

const save = () => {
  const values = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Notifications_Key");
  let datestoredValues = JSON.parse(values); //
  const dateConvert =
    datestoredValues.storedDateValue.ampm == "pm" // here in my time picker i passed isAmPm prop so if seelcted time was PM then it updates trigger with this value.
    ?
    datestoredValues.storedDateValue.hours + 12 :
    datestoredValues.storedDateValue.hours;
  const lastnotificationId = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: {
      // content goes here..
    },
    trigger: {
      hour: dateConvert, // Here it converts to 24 formet
      minute: // miutes
        repeats: true,
    },
  });
  alert("Remainder was set!!!!");
  storeData();
};
```

---